# Angular controller not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm newbie to angular
My angular controller is:

```
var chatApp = angular.module('chatApp.controllers', []);

chatApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.user_name="name";
$scope.user_password="name";
}]);
```

the app.js is:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('chatApp', [
'ui.router',
'chatApp.filters',
'chatApp.services',
'chatApp.directives',
'chatApp.controllers'
]).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "partials/login.html",
        controller : "loginController"
    })
});
```

login.html is:

```
<div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="" method="post">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <input name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="{{user_name}}" />
            <div class="user-icon"></div>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="{{user_password}}" />
            <div class="pass-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I've used stateprovider for routing.
But, it's not showing anything in placeholder. What is the reason?

Comment: i don't see `ng-controller="loginController"` anywhere in your html. this would be needed if angular is supposed to wrap the portion into a scope and render the directives according to your controller's scope variables.

Comment: Please put your code in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @jhohlfeld: No he doesn't need it, it's placed in the $stateProvider.

Any errors ? Did you init all those specified module dependencies ?

Does your browser support placeholders?

Comment: these answers show how many ways there are to start an angular project

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem using ng-model instead of {{}}.

```
<div class="content">
            <input name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="username" ng-model="user_name" />
            <div class="user-icon"></div>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="password" ng-model="user_password"/>
            <div class="pass-icon"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me if I say ng-controller = "loginController" in the html-

```
<div ng-controller = 'loginController'>
<div id="wrapper">
    <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="" method="post">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <input name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="{{user_name}}" />
            <div class="user-icon"></div>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="{{user_password}}" />
            <div class="pass-icon"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here's a JSBin with it working: http://jsbin.com/aDuJIku/265/edit?html,js,output

This solution doesn't include ui-router, but it should work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var chatApp = angular.module('chatApp.controllers', []);

    chatApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope','$timeout', function($scope,$timeout) {

        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.user_name="name";
            $scope.user_password="name";
        },100);

    }]);
```

Answer (score -1):

you just have to change to [RouteProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider), In your case you just do:

```
angular.module('chatApp', [ 'ngRoute' 'ui.router','chatApp.filters','chatApp.services', 'chatApp.directives', 'chatApp.controllers'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', { templateUrl: "partials/login.html", controller: "loginController" })
});
```

please make sure that you have angular-route js included.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Hope this help you! ;)

Here's some examples for you [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/)

Answer (score -1):

Below mentioned code works.

Note: If somebody tries to run this code in preview its not going to work. JS and HTML code needs to be copied in separate file and use the names mentioned.

```js
var myContrlApp = angular.module('ContrlApp', []);
myContrlApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    var person = {
        firstName: "Keith",
        lastName: "Jackson",
    };
    $scope.message = "Welcome, Angular !";
    $scope.person = person;
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ContrlApp">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/script.js"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />-->
    <title>Angular JS Tryout</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div>
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>
        <div>
            <div>First name: {{person.firstName}}</div>
            <div>Last name: {{person.lastName}}</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```